# Reading several images from sub folders.. C++/opencv

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I would like to know how to implement a code to read images in folders, for example; I have a folder with name "images" and this folder has sub folders which every sub folder contains many images. I want to read all these images by using c++/opencv in order to use these images to extract features from them all.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a folder and file enumeration API.
Some portable APIs include [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) and [STLSoft](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/group__group____library____filesystem.html).
This is unrelated to OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you use the opendir, readdir and closedir functions. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/readdir.html. You need to do this recursively to walk the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way might be for you to use [nftw](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw).  It will do all the directory traversal for you (with options to control how) and execute your callback function.  There is a small code example on the man page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filesystem of boost to iterate through folders for reading. Use back_iterator.